# android stop background service after activity crash

Tags: android, android-service, ondestroy, uncaught-exception, uncaughtexceptionhandler

At the beginning, I would like apologize for bad english.

There is my problem:

I have a service in android which runs on background when is activity running. (This service synchronize user data with server with specified time intervals).

```
public class CService extends Service
{
   private Boolean isDestroyed;



@Override
    public int onStartCommand (Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
            if (intent != null)
            {
                   new Thread(new Runnable()
                   {
                   //run new thread to disable flush memory for android and destroy this service
                           @Override
                           public void run ()
                           {
                                     this.isDestroyed = Boolean.FALSE
                                     while(!this.isDestroyed)
                                     {
                                     //loop until service isn't destroyed
                                     }
                            }

                    }).start();
            }
            return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy ()
    {
           //THIS ISNT CALLED FROM uncaughtException IN ACTIVITY BUT from onDestroy method is this called.

           //when is service destroyed then onDestroy is called and loop finish
           this.isDestroyed = Boolean.TRUE;
    }

}
```

And is started from activity in onCreateMethod. This activity implements Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler and register in onCreate method to catch all unexpected exceptions in activity. When something in activity throw exception method uncaughtException is called and and service should stop with stopService(serviceIntent); But onDestoy in service isn't called. But when is onDestroy method in activity called (user push then back button) service is stopped succesfully and onDestoroy in CService is called.

```
    public class CActivity extends Activity implements Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler
    {
            private Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler defaultUEH;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {

            this.defaultUEH = Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();

            // create intent for service
            Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, CService.class);
            // run service
            startService(serviceIntent);

            //set default handler when application crash
            Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(this);
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        }

        @Override
        public void uncaughtException (Thread thread, Throwable ex)
        {
            //THIS DOESN'T WORK

            //when global exception in activity is throws then this method is called. 
            Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, CService.class);
            //method to service stop is called. BUT THIS METHOD DON'T CALL onDestroy in CService
            stopService(serviceIntent);
            defaultUEH.uncaughtException(thread, ex);       
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy ()
        {
            //this work fine
            Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, CService.class);
            stopService(serviceIntent);
            super.onDestroy();
            }


    }
```

I need stop background service when activity crashes. Bacause when android close activity and start previous activity in stack (Which is login screen) no user is now logged.

Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: is your service run from another process?

Comment: service is run and stopped from same activity run in onCreate method and stooped in uncaughtException method.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
    Thread.currentThread().setUncaughtExceptionHandler(this);
```

**UPD**
this is default android exception handler

```
private static class UncaughtHandler implements Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler {
        public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
            try {
                // Don't re-enter -- avoid infinite loops if crash-reporting crashes.
                if (mCrashing) return;
                mCrashing = true;

                if (mApplicationObject == null) {
                    Slog.e(TAG, "*** FATAL EXCEPTION IN SYSTEM PROCESS: " + t.getName(), e);
                } else {
                    Slog.e(TAG, "FATAL EXCEPTION: " + t.getName(), e);
                }

                // Bring up crash dialog, wait for it to be dismissed
                ActivityManagerNative.getDefault().handleApplicationCrash(
                        mApplicationObject, new ApplicationErrorReport.CrashInfo(e));
            } catch (Throwable t2) {
                try {
                    Slog.e(TAG, "Error reporting crash", t2);
                } catch (Throwable t3) {
                    // Even Slog.e() fails!  Oh well.
                }
            } finally {
                // Try everything to make sure this process goes away.
                Process.killProcess(Process.myPid());
                System.exit(10);
            }
        }
    }
```

I believe you don't get the onDestroy() call, because the default android exception handler simply destroys entire process System.exit(). You can try not to call defaultUEH.uncaughtException(thread, ex);   or call it later after(if) your service is destoryed.

Comment: This don't work. Because setUncaughtExceptionHandler(this); is staic method and currentThread() isn't static method. But thanks for reply

Comment: setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler is static

Comment: your right I using a static method. But if I using no static method setUncaughtExceptionHandler, stopService() doesn't call onDestroy too.

Answer (score 1):

Dude, by the way why do you perform you actions in onCreate method?
As documentations says this method is called from the main thread, i actually wondering how does it even work. You should do any heavy calculations from another Thread.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

> When a Service component is actually created, for either of these
>   reasons, all that the system actually does is instantiate the
>   component and call its onCreate() and any other appropriate callbacks
>   on the main thread. It is up to the Service to implement these with
>   the appropriate behavior, such as creating a secondary thread in which
>   it does its work.

Comment: Sorry I do mistake when I posting question here, Because I run service from onStartCommand instead of onCreate. I correct first post and correct question. I not copy-paste into question and when I write then code I do error. And I using another thread to prevent to android destroy service.